# Confused about how to use exchanger in java

Tags: java

As with basically every exchanger task, I have a producer filling up an empty buffer2, a consumer clearing a full buffer1 and when each thread is done, they should exchange their respective buffers.

I am really unsure about where and how to apply the exchange. I defined readyconsumer and readyproducer as booleans, so that a third thread can check whether it's time to exchange the buffers once both are true. This should solve the problem I had doing it with two threads, where the program was stuck with both threads at wait() (which it unfortunately still is).

This is what the code looks like at the moment. Can anyone help me in which class I have to exchange and at what point in the code? Thank you very much in advance!

```
    class Buffer {
        static boolean readyconsumer, readyproducer = false;

        volatile int count; // number of put actions
        static int max = 10;

        Buffer() {
        count = 0;
        }

        public synchronized void put() {
            if (count == max) {
                readyproducer = true;
                System.out.println("          wait ");
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            count++;
            System.out.println("put " + count);
            notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized void get() {
            if (count == 0) {
                readyconsumer = true;
                System.out.println("          wait");
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            count--;
            System.out.println("get " + count);
            notifyAll();
        }
    }


class CheckandSwitch extends ProdCon {
    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            if (Buffer.readyconsumer && Buffer.readyproducer) {
                try {
                    ProdCon.buffer2 = exchanger.exchange(ProdCon.buffer1);
                    ProdCon.buffer1 = exchanger.exchange(ProdCon.buffer2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                Buffer.readyconsumer = false;
                Buffer.readyproducer = false;
                buffer1.count = 0;
                buffer2.count = 10;
                notifyAll();
            }

        }
    }

}

class Consumer extends ProdCon {
    static Buffer buffer;

    Consumer(Buffer b) {
        super();
        buffer = b;
        b.count = 10;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            consume();
            buffer.get();
        }
    }

    private void consume() {
        System.out.println("consume");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

class Producer extends ProdCon {
    static Buffer buffer;

    Producer(Buffer b) {
        super();
        buffer = b;
        b.count = 0;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            produce();
            buffer.put();
        }
    }

    private void produce() {
        System.out.println("produce ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ProdCon extends Thread {
    static Exchanger<Buffer> exchanger = new Exchanger<Buffer>();
    static Buffer buffer1, buffer2 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        buffer1 = new Buffer();
        buffer2 = new Buffer();
        new Consumer(buffer1).start();
        new Producer(buffer2).start();
        new CheckandSwitch().start();

    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use a third thread. But I'd recommend using higher level constructs than `wait()`. Your code has a lot of other funky things going on too. Is this an assignment? Because I'd use the existing classes instead of creating my own buffer classes etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an assignment and apart from the CheckandSwitch class, which I created, I kept most of the code that was given. I guess I'll have to take another hard look at javadoc so I understand it better. But thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html).

Here's the code from the javadoc tweaked into a working example.

```
class DataBuffer<T> {

    T data = null;

    public boolean isFull() {
        return data != null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return data == null;
    }

    public T get() {
        T d = data;
        data = null;
        return d;
    }

    public void put(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class FillAndEmpty {

    Exchanger<DataBuffer<Integer>> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();
    DataBuffer<Integer> initialEmptyBuffer = new DataBuffer<>();
    DataBuffer<Integer> initialFullBuffer = new DataBuffer<>();
    int countDown = 10;

    class FillingLoop implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataBuffer currentBuffer = initialEmptyBuffer;
            try {
                while (currentBuffer != null && countDown > 0) {
                    addToBuffer(currentBuffer);
                    if (currentBuffer.isFull()) {
                        currentBuffer = exchanger.exchange(currentBuffer);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

        private void addToBuffer(DataBuffer<Integer> currentBuffer) {
            currentBuffer.put(countDown--);
        }
    }

    class EmptyingLoop implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataBuffer<Integer> currentBuffer = initialFullBuffer;
            try {
                while (currentBuffer != null) {
                    takeFromBuffer(currentBuffer);
                    if (currentBuffer.isEmpty()) {
                        currentBuffer = exchanger.exchange(currentBuffer);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

        private void takeFromBuffer(DataBuffer<Integer> currentBuffer) {
            System.out.println(currentBuffer.get());
        }
    }

    void start() {
        new Thread(new FillingLoop()).start();
        new Thread(new EmptyingLoop()).start();
    }
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    new FillAndEmpty().start();
}
```

Comment: Would you say this is thread-safe ? There is single instance of Consumer & Producer. They exchange a wrapper around a array-list. There would be only one thread at a time working on exchanged wrapper - so, it should be thread-safe. Right ?